# Python- Function which deletes an element from a list by name

Tags: python, list, function

Hi there i am trying to figure out how to delete an element from a list by using the specific name of that element in the list. so there will be an input which the user will be asked 'who do you want to delete from the list: ' and they will enter the first name. i cant seem to work out how to do this. ive got all the details of the individual people saved in a variable called "student" which contains their name, their course etc.

```
def removestudent():
    for studentName in student:
    del(student)

input("insert the user you wish to remove: "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to pass your argument to function `elem` is the element that you want to remove from list an `l` is the list:

```
>>> def removestudent(elem,l):
...     l.remove(elem)
...     return l
... 
>>> l=[1,2,3,4]
>>> removestudent(input("insert the user you wish to remove: "),l)
insert the user you wish to remove: 3
[1, 2, 4]
```

But there is one problem here if the elem is not in your list python will raise a `ValueError` : for get ride of that you need to use a `try-except` statement :

```
>>> def removestudent(elem,l):
...    try :
...     l.remove(elem)
...     return l
...    except ValueError :
...     print 'The element is not in list please enter a valid element !!'
... 
>>> removestudent(input("insert the user you wish to remove: "),l)
insert the user you wish to remove: 7
The element is not in list please enter a valid element !!
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you want [`remove`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

```
>>> l = ['a','b','c','e']
>>> l.remove('a')
>>> l
['b', 'c', 'e']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
   l = ['a, 'b','c']
   a = [x for x in l if x != 'a']
   a
   >>>['b','c']
```